# Populating template from 2 worksheets; data from 2nd worksheet not copying to correct line after first completed template

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an individual worksheet for each employee based on a template which is populated from two worksheets. I can get the Employee_Data to populate correctly. (Thanks to assistance from Tim Williams.)  However, when copying the JobHist_DataWorking data only the first completed template is on the correct line; subsequent worksheets are populated further down.  The job history information should begin pasting to line 19 for the first job record.

Being a novice coder, I played with the code and have managed to get the last employee to populate on line 40 rather than line 260 as my earlier attempts netted. However, it needs to be on line 19.  I looked at the Do While/Until Loop but could not get the placements in my current code to run. Below is my code as it currently works but not correctly.

EDIT: Code has been updated as suggested.

EDIT #2: Code has been updated to reflect it working correctly thanks to help of Darrell H.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wsCopy As Worksheet, v
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Template")
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Employee_Data")
    Set sht = wb.Sheets("JobHist_DataWorking")

    x = 19

    For i = 2 To sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set wsCopy = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

        wsCopy.Name = sh.Range("F" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C1").Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C2").Value = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C3").Value = sh.Range("H" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C4").Value = sh.Range("I" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C5").Value = sh.Range("J" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C6").Value = sh.Range("S" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C7").Value = sh.Range("V" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C8").Value = sh.Range("W" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C9").Value = sh.Range("X" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C11").Value = sh.Range("L" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C12").Value = sh.Range("AH" & i).Value
         v = sh.Range("AJ" & i).Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then wsCopy.Range("C13").Value = v
        wsCopy.Range("C14").Value = sh.Range("AM" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C15").Value = sh.Range("AP" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("C16").Value = sh.Range("AQ" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("H1").Value = sh.Range("F" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("H3").Value = sh.Range("K" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("N1").Value = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        wsCopy.Range("N11").Value = sh.Range("N" & i).Value


          For j = 2 To sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
               With Worksheets("JobHist_DataWorking")
                    If Not sht.Range("A" & j).Value = wsCopy.Range("C1") Then
                        x = 19
                        Else
                            sht.Range(.Cells(j, 3), .Cells(j, 4)).Copy
                               wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(x, 1), wsCopy.Cells(x, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            sht.Range(.Cells(j, 6), .Cells(j, 8)).Copy
                               wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(x, 3), wsCopy.Cells(x, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            sht.Range(.Cells(j, 9), .Cells(j, 12)).Copy
                              wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(x, 7), wsCopy.Cells(x, 10)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                     x = x + 1
                    End If
                End With
              Next j

     Next i

End Sub
```

The first employee has three job records which are currently populating on lines 19, 20 and 21 as expected. The second employee also has three job records, but they are populating on lines 22, 23 and 24. The third employee has two job records which are populating on lines 25 and 26.  This progression down the template continues such that the 10th and 11th employees who have only one job record each are populating on lines 39 and 40 respectively.

The job history for each employee should begin on line 19. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Each of the lines where you paste need to be updated to include the worksheet in the `.cells` portion of the range.  For example, `wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(x,3), wsCopy.Cells(x,5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.  Otherwise they may not be going in the correct worksheet.

Comment: Also, all 3 `If` statements are the same.  Why not just combine?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to update the paste cell references. As for combining the three If statements I'm open to suggestions.  Note that the copy from range of columns 3 to 12 skip column 5 and the past to range of columns 1 to 10 skip column 6.  Thanks.

Comment: I could not recreate the error.  `x` reset to 19 before each new sheet was created.  Try using `F8` to step through and watch the value of `x` in the locals window to see how the value changes.

Comment: Thanks Darrell H. I learned something new. I didn't know about the locals window.  I think I see what's happening but not sure how to fix it. The values of j and x are increasing as the code works it way through the JobHist_DataWorking spreadsheet and it is cycling though all rows every time a new sheet is created. I'm thinking I need an if then else statement for it to do nothing if the if statement is false else do the copy paste. Would this be the right approach to this problem?

Comment: I tried adding IF NOT sht.Range("A" & j).Value = wsCopy.Range("C1") Then Else... but the outcome was the same.

Comment: I moved the placement of "x = 19" and "x = x + 1" and got it to run as desired. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  It helps to step through and see the variable change to figure out why it doesn’t do what we expect.